# How can I set the size of a UITextView to 100?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this code to create a UITextView that's added to a footer.

```
public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    var txtView = new UITextView
    {
        Editable = false,
        Text = "Select or deselect cards from the list above and they will added or removed from the card deck,",
        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Justified,
        TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 5, right: 5),
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent.ToUIColor()
    };

    txtView.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
    return txtView;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can make this UITextView had a height of 100?

Answer (score 0):

```
public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    var txtView = new UITextView(new Rectangle(0,0,0,100))
    {
        ..........
    };

    ........
}
```

Try this hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Override the method `GetHeightForFooter`

   ```
   public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
   {
       return 100;
   }
   ```
2. set frame on UITextView

   ```
   public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
   {
       var txtView = new UITextView
       {
           Frame = new CGRect(0,0, tableView.Frame.Width,100),
           Editable = false,
           Text = "Select or deselect cards from the list above and they will added or removed from the card deck,",
           TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Justified,
           TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 5, right: 5),
           BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent.ToUIColor()
       };

       txtView.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
       return txtView;
   }
   ```